# How i make the drop menu Show up smoothly with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, web

I made a drop Menu, the dropped part has `display: none;` when it be Clicked the `JS` give it class `motherHover` what give it `display: grid;` to make it visible.

But the problem is that the menu appears One-shot.

How to make the drop menu Show up smoothly with pure JS?

```js
function fgf(){
    var hoverElement = document.querySelector(".father"),
    tragtedElement = document.querySelector("#dds");

    tragtedElement.classList.toggle("motherHover");
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;

}
.father{
}
.mother{
    display: none;
}

.asd {
    display: grid;

}
.motherHover{
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <ul>
        <li class="father" onclick="fgf()">
            <button>
                Drop Menu
            </button>
        </li>
        <li id="dds" class="mother" >
            <ul class="asd">
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its usually done with `max-height` and transitions.

```js
function fgf(){
    let asd = document.querySelector(".asd");
    asd.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.asd {
    display: grid;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 500ms;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
.open {
   max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <ul>
        <li class="father" onclick="fgf()">
            <button>
                Drop Menu
            </button>
        </li>
        <li id="dds" class="mother" >
            <ul class="asd">
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
                <i>g</i>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```